# How to add animation to the multiple instances of images?

Tags: animation, javafx

How can we apply the animations to random instances of images?
I have tried , but it only apply the animation to one instance of image.

```
public class TimeLines extends Application {

 AnchorPane root;
Image img;

private final Random random = new Random();
private final double shs = 10.0; // Star Hand Size
ImageView imgView;
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Image img=new Image(new FileInputStream("plus.png")); 
     root = new AnchorPane();
     for(int cont = 0 ; cont < 15 ; cont++)  
     {  
         imgView=new ImageView();
          imgView.setImage(img);
          imgView.setTranslateX( Math.random() * 800 );  
         imgView.setTranslateY( Math.random() * 400 ); 
        root.getChildren().add(imgView);
        play();   
     }
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}


private void play() {
    final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
   timeline.setCycleCount(2);
    timeline.setAutoReverse(true);
       final KeyValue kFade = new KeyValue(imgView.opacityProperty(), 0);
        final KeyFrame kf = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), kFade);
        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(kf);

        timeline.setOnFinished(e -> {            
                play();       });
        timeline.play();}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

now its complete code;

[output of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PvSC.jpg)

it only apply animation to one instance of image, but i want to animate all the objects randomly

Comment: I have edited the, and now provide the complete and verifiable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are only getting one with a transition is because of this line `imgView=new ImageView();` it is only setting the trasition for the last one if you create a list and add all the them to that list then set key frames for all of them it should work

Working example

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private AnchorPane root;
    private ArrayList<ImageView> imageViewArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Image img=new Image(new FileInputStream("plus.png"));
        root = new AnchorPane();
        for(int cont = 0 ; cont < 15 ; cont++)
        {
            ImageView imgView=new ImageView();
            imgView.setImage(img);
            imgView.setTranslateX( Math.random() * 800 );
            imgView.setTranslateY( Math.random() * 400 );

            imageViewArrayList.add(imgView);
            root.getChildren().add(imgView);
            //play();//I don't think you need this
        }

        new Timer().schedule(//Will keep infinitely firing every second
                new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        play();
                    }
                },
                0,
                1000);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void play() {
        final Timeline timeline = new Timeline();
        timeline.setCycleCount(2);
        timeline.setAutoReverse(true);

        //For animating All
        //for (ImageView imageView : imageViewArrayList) { 
        //    final KeyValue kFade = new KeyValue(imageView.opacityProperty(), 0);
        //    timeline.getKeyFrames().add(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000), kFade));
        //}

        timeline.getKeyFrames().clear();//Remove Last

        int randomIndex = (int) (Math.random() * imageViewArrayList.size());//Pick random Index

        timeline.getKeyFrames().add(//Add random index
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),
                        new KeyValue(imageViewArrayList.get(randomIndex).opacityProperty(), 0)));


        //timeline.setOnFinished(e -> play());//I don't think you need this
        timeline.play();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, its really helpful. Due to such glitch i was stuck! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

my idea which may be helpful for this case:

- store all *ImageViews* in a list
- create a *Random* with the list size
- create a method to apply animation to the *ImageView* indexed by the
  value that *Random* returned

Sample code:

```
//create list to store all ImageViews  
private static List<ImageView> imageViewList = new LinkedList<>();

//add ImageView in list in each iteration (each image created)  
for(int cont = 0 ; cont < 15 ; cont++){  
          imgView=new ImageView();
          imgView.setImage(img);
          imgView.setTranslateX( Math.random() * 800 );  
          imgView.setTranslateY( Math.random() * 400 ); 
          root.getChildren().add(imgView);
          //new line added to your code
          imageViewList.add(imgView);
     }

//create random object
Random rand = new Random();
// Obtain a number between [0 - (listSize-1)].
//int n = rand.nextInt(imageViewList.size()-1);

//animate a random image, put it in a loop to continue animation 
//use while(true){...} for infinite loop
animateImageViewIn(rand.nextInt(imageViewList.size()-1));

//create method to animate ImageView in given index in list
animateImageViewIn(int index){
    //your animation code
    //...
    //apply animation to the random ImageView
    final KeyValue kFade = new KeyValue(imageVewList.get(index).opacityProperty(), 0);
    //continue your code
    //...
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: you should always test the code you are posting in an answer ;) And: a) please learn java naming conventions and stick to them b) don't use statics

Comment: Thank You for help. You are right, i forgot to add the images in List actually.

Comment: @kleopatra thnx for advices, about my answer, i was trying to give an idea of solution (there are many), so i tried to describe it briefly. About the "not tested" i was in a hurry, and didnt have time to open intelliJ (slow pc) to test the code, and it was related to any miss-typing and formatting, not about the functionality of the code :)  (I'm new to this forum on asking/answering)

Comment: @Abbasi no problem, I'm glad it helped you. You can "Accept" my answer if it solved your problem, so others with the same problem can find their solution faster :)